# How to add a text(string) inside a div box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've tried using `document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]').innerHTML = "test123"` and `document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]').innerHTML = "test123"` as well as `.innerText` but it's still not working. Because it's not working, I've to write down inside the div box in html file. It works that way but it's not practical. What did I do wrong here ?

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.calc-interface {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

output {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.previous-operand {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 220px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.current-operand {
  display: flex;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  flex: 1;
  width: 220px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.size-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.numbers {
  display: inline-block;
  gap: 4px;
  width: 220px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#digits {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.operator {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script>
    document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]').innerHTML = "test";
    document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]').innerHTML = "test";
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calc-interface">
    <div class="output">
      <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand" id="previous-operand"> </div>
      <div data-current-operand class="current-operand" id="current-operand"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="numbers">
      <button data-number id="digits"> 1 </button>
      <button data-number id="digits"> 2 </button>
      <button data-number id="digits"> 3 </button>
      <button data-operation id="+" class="operator"> + </button>
      <button data-number id="digits"> 4 </button>
      <button data-number id="digits"> 5 </button>
      <button data-number id="digits"> 6 </button>
      <button data-operation id="-" class="operator"> - </button>
      <button data-number id="digits"> 7 </button>
      <button data-number id="digits"> 8 </button>
      <button data-number id="digits"> 9 </button>
      <button data-operation id="*" class="operator"> * </button>
      <button data-all-clear id="clear" class="operator"> C </button>
      <button data-number id="digits" class="zero"> 0 </button>
      <button data-equal id="equal" class="operator"> = </button>
      <button data-operation id="/" class="operator"> / </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine, are you sure the dom is ready when you're running it?

Comment: @averroes divs can hold text

Comment: Do you see the console errors above? I'd guess that they also appear in your page. This is due to the reason Lissy93 mentioned.

Comment: Move the script to the bottom of the body and will work.

Comment: As Jairo Py point out. it works ! but why is it like that though ? any references I can refer to ? btw other alternatives is by adding 'defer' in the script .

Comment: See the two linked duplicates. There's lots of information there.